# Kendo Grid : How to show the same filter option in Row and Column filter?

Tags: kendo-grid

How to show the same filter option in Row and Column filter?

I have set the filter operator as

```
column.filterable = {
    ui: triggerFilter,
    cell: {
        template: triggerFilter,
    },
    operators: {
        string: {
            eq: "Equal to",
            neq: "Not equal to"
        }
    }
};
```

But it seems to only have affect on the column filter, see the image.
[image]

Comment: Have a loot at the example and see if it solves your issue?
**http://dojo.telerik.com/@D_Learning/ihOP/3**

Comment: That will set it for all columns. I just need it for the first column. I think this is a bug in Kendo UI.

Comment: Yes that is correct, for the row filterable mode there is no option to set it for column wise. Either it sets it automatically by its Data type or it takes up the operators which you provide for all the Columns